# Кастомный hook для мультиязычных приложений

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Есть приложения мультиязычная.Перевод если есть приходит с сервера либо находитсья в файле `translations.js`.

Так выглядит мой  компонент с переводом с сервера и без.

```
import { LanguageContext } from "./languageContext";
import languages from "./translations";

function someComponent(){
  const {language} = useContext(LanguageContext);

  //вот так извлекаю переводы из файла translations.js

  const {UsersComponentEn,
         UsersInfoComponentLanguagesEn,
         UsersInfoComponentEn} = languages.en;
    const {UsersComponentDe,
        UsersInfoComponentLanguagesDe,
        UsersComponentDe} = languages.de;


   return (
      {/* тут много ненужного jsx кода */}
       {personal.data.map(el => {
             return <MainInfo name={language === "en" || language === undefined ? el.full_name_en : el.full_name_de}
                     adress={language === "en" || language === undefined ? el.address_en : el.address_de}
                     key={el.id} />
           })} 

      {/* и простой перевод который не приходит с сервера */}
       <h3 className="title_thin text_muted">{language === "en" || language === undefined ? UserInfoComponentEn : UserInfoComponentDe}</h3>
   )
}
```

И вот таких компонентов очень много.

Вопрос в том что есть ли какой нибудь **best practise** (чтобы не писать тернарый оператор либо извлекать каждый перевод из файла `translations.js`)   для таких ситуациях что вы делаете чтобы не писать так может  у кого есть кастомный `hook` для этого.

Answer (score 0):

Создаёте файл перевода всего интерфейса и тому подобного, в стиле:

```
const language= ['en', 'ru', ...]

const translations= {
   buttonAddName = ['add', 'добавить', ...],
   menuName = ['menu', 'меню', ...]
}
```

При загрузке страницы определяете язык клиента или позволяете вручную его выбирать пользователю.

После определения языка находите его индекс в массиве language, к примеру 1, после чего делаете .map итерацию translations возвращая все значения с индексом 1.

```
const translations= {
   buttonAddName ='добавить',
   menuName = 'меню'
}
```

Экспортируете перевод контекстом и пользуетесь им во всех компонентах:

```
<button>translations.menuName<button />
```

При смене языка вешаете хук на повторную итерации и весь интерфейс обновится.

Comment: А можно  самый простой пример в https://codesandbox.io/?А то так я не очень понял если честно.